# Chrome 53 visual scrolling bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, scroll

since Chrome updated to version 53 it has introduced a new bug in my application. 
I have JS-generated html in left panel of my app which requires scrolling. I've been using the `perfect-scrollbar` plugin to make the scrolling prettier. 
However now whenever I expand one of the "li"s in the left panel and scroll, its background, some images and some other elements stay fixed and refuse to move. It looks like this: 
[image]

I have tried disabling the scrollbar plugin but to no avail, it "works" the same with the default browser scrollbar. Thank you for any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Can You please post a GIF similar to this one without the plugin?

Comment: Here it is: https://gyazo.com/345647f3b89375036cdb7d9965a0703b

Comment: I dont see the problem on this native scrollbar, so I assume it is a bug with the plugin you are using.

Comment: The problem is still there, the background behind the li elements, the images on the two buttons above them etc. are not scrolling. It is supposed to work like this: https://gyazo.com/3ebe2439d0b8d10b61760a98cbe6b1af (tested in Edge)